# How can I solve: Error installing linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic

Tags: virtualbox

[image]

How can I solve this?
Ubuntu version is 22.04 and virtual box version is 7.0
I have already installed one Ubuntu vm on this virtual box.
Is it the reason why this new one not getting installed?